# Trying to open ArcGIS created Dbf file in Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, gis, arcgis, esri, dbf

I am using a GIS program called ArcGIS to create a .dbf file from shapefile data. I have tried opening the .dbf file in sqlite3. sqlite3 stated "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database". What is causing this error? Why can't I open the .dbf in sqlite3?

When I open the dbf file in Excel I have no issues.

[image: Sqlite Error Message]

[image: Dfb opened in Excel]

Edit: I am new user to Stack Overflow. SO I am confused at why there no explaination for -1 Vote. What does it mean? And if I get no input into why down votes happen, how can I learn to write better questions?

Edit 2: Since getting an answer, I have researched more and understand better that dbf files are old format that has no SQL component to it.  Originally I thought (wrongly) if dbf and sqlite are both databases then they must be compatible. When just starting out, basic questions to you may not be so basic to others.

Comment: The downvote probably means somebody thinks this is not a question about **programming** or you don't seem to be showing any programming effort you have made yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .dbf file is a [dBase database file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf). [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) is a different database system with a completely different database file format. SQLite clients are not made to handle .dbf files. So the behavior you see is expected.

If you really need to access this data with a SQLite client, you could use ArcGIS's [Create SQLite Database tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-sqlite-database.htm) and copy the data from the shapefile to a SQLite database.

Comment: No wonder Sqlite couldn't open the dbf file--if it is not supported. Thanks for the link to Create SQLite Tool.